# Result query to single array of string

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to transform the result of an Eloquent query into a single array of strings.

What my query currently gives:
(I apply a ->toArray() to initial query to get that :)

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "title" => "User"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "title" => "Premium"
  ]
]
```

What I would like it to give me:

`['User', 'Premium'];`

My query :

`Rank::where('strength', '<', $this->rank->strength)->select('title')->get();`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-list-of-column-values):

```
Rank::where('strength', '<', $this->rank->strength)->pluck('title');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want exactly same array response instead of collection, You can add toArray() function at the last

```
$ranks = Rank::where('strength', '<', $this->rank->strength)
        ->pluck('title')->toArray();
```